# Do all points in a scheme have a curve through them?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a scheme of $dim >1$ over a field $k$. Let $p \in X$ be a closed point.

> Will there always be a curve i.e 1-dim subvariety passing through $p$? [If the answer is no, is it because of some pathological example due to the field being finite etc?]

> Can something more extreme happen like there being a scheme of $dim >1$ with no curves as subvarieties (maybe over finite fields)?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is integral and of finite type over $k$. I will prove by induction on ${\rm dim}(X)>0$ that there is a closed irreducible curve in $X$ going through $p$. First we might assume that $X$ is affine, because if there is a such a curve inside an open affine containing $p$, then we might replace it by its Zariski closure in $X$. So suppose $X={\rm Spec}(R)$ and let $r$ be an element of the maximal ideal of $p$. Let $I$ be one of the minimal prime ideals of $r$. Then ${\rm cod}(I)=1$ by Krull's theorem and thus ${\rm dim}(R/I)={\rm dim}(R)-1$ (eg by Th. 2.5.23 in Q. Liu's book).

Comment: ... Now $p$ lies in the integral closed subscheme of $X$ defined by $I$, so we can apply the inductive hypothesis to complete the proof.

Comment: @DamianRössler that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.

Comment: Sorry in argument, you have to take the minimal prime ideal $I$ contained in the maximal ideal of $p$ (there is one eg by Atiyah-MacDonald, Prop. 1.11 ii)).